# Getting Legacy Qt Project to work with ATL in a machine independent way

Tags: qt, qmake, atl

I am trying to get a Qt project (that is using ATL to communicate with a COM server) to build on Qt 6.2.

So far, I have gotten it to build successfully (at least on my machine) with the following addition in the .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/atlmfc/include/"
win32:LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/atlmfc/lib/x64/atls.lib"
```

- `INCLUDEPATH` fixes the compile error saying that it is unable to open `ATLComTime.h`
- `win32:LIBS` obviously adds the required lib to the project

**Question:** I'd rather not write "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/...` in my .pro file -- is there a more portable way of telling qmake where to find the required ATL support?

(Or maybe there even is a setting telling qmake that this is an ATL project?)

If it makes any difference: the same project builds on VS 2022 without the changes above, so I am guessing there is some magic switch that VS knows about.

Comment: Any reason for not using the recommended cmake build system with Qt 6 that solves this for you with cmake config files?

Comment: There can be multiple instances of Visual Studio on a given PC (with different versions such as 2017, 2019, 2022, previews, etc.) and there can be multiple versions of the ATLMFC tooling (including x86, x64, ATM, with spectre enabled, etc.). So it really depends on what you're looking for, what you assume, etc. The fact it builds directly with Visual Studio just tells us Visual Studio is not broken and knows what was installed depending on context, but it's not as simple as a "magic switch". The VS setup is itself programmable: https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere

Comment: Well, I should have mentioned that it is a legacy qmake-project. A CMake transition is on the roadmap but rather long-term. We are looking for a short-term fix at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Simon's answer, here is what I added to my .pro file:

```
VSWHERE = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"

ATLMFC_PATH = $$system($$shell_quote($$VSWHERE) -latest -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 -property installationPath)
ATLMFC_PATH = $$replace(ATLMFC_PATH, \\\\, /)

# ATLMFC_PATH should now be something like "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional"

ATLMFC_PATH = $$ATLMFC_PATH/VC/Tools/MSVC/$$(VCToolsVersion)/atlmfc

INCLUDEPATH += "$$ATLMFC_PATH/include"
win32:LIBS += "$$ATLMFC_PATH/lib/x64/atls.lib"
```

We call `vswhere.exe` (which is found at the same spot on all machines in our team) and get the first half of the desired path. Then we add the remainder that (hopefully) looks the same on upcoming versions and insert the value of environment variable `VCToolsVersion`, hence the $$(...) -- round brackets.

Finally we add the obtained path with corresponding extensions to `INCLUDEPATH` and `LIBS`.

This should keep us in business until we finally get to the CMake transition.